# Checking whether an image is part of another

Tags: java, image, lambda

I have the following code (slightly modified for simplicity). It checks whether a given image A (the template) is part of another image B. To handle different sizes, image B is scaled as long as a match is found or some minimum/maximum image size is reached.

The naive implementation for this is quite straight forward but I'm not happy with it:

1. The code within the two while loops is almost identical.
2. Handling scaling down and scaling up in two different loops is inefficient in a lot of cases (e.g. when the first iteration of the second while loop would find a match but we still need to go through all iterations of the first one).

Can you offer some suggestions on how to improve my code?

```
double bestMatch = 0;

while (image.width() > MIN_IMAGE_WIDTH) {
   match = match(image, template); // for the sake of simplicity let this return a double
   if (match > bestMatch) {
      bestMatch = match;
   }
   if (match.maxVal >= threshold) {
      foundMatch = true;
      break;
   }
   image = scaleImage(image, 0.9);
}

image = originalImage;
while (image.width() < MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH) {
   match = match(image, template);
   if (match > bestMatch) {
      bestMatch = match;
   }
   if (match.maxVal >= threshold) {
      foundMatch = true;
      break;
   }
   image = scaleImage(image, 1.1);
}

// do something with bestMatch
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second point:

Why not include the `foundMatch` in the condition of the `while`?

```
while (!foundMatch && image.width() < MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH) {
```

That way you don't run the second loop at all if a match was found in the first.

---

Having a couple of duplicate lines isn't a bad thing. It's obvious what the lines do and what the difference is between the 2 loops (1 scaling up, the other scaling down). So at least in my opinion there is nothing wrong with having both loops like this.

---

I'm actually most surprised that you need to handle scaling at all though. One of the most popular image comparison algorithms these days uses [SIFT (Scale invariant feature transform)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) which, as the name implies is scale invariant.